# Can't edit connections/connect/disconnet in Gnome NetworkManager applet

Tags: 12.04, networking, network-manager, gnome-panel, applet

since a few days I'm seeing a weird behaviour of the NetworkManager-applet in Gnome.

The "Edit Connections" line is greyed out, so I'm not able to call the nm-connection-editor. From the command line everything works as expected.

Additionally the applet (or NetworkManager) is no longer able to connect to my LAN, although it tries...

When I connect to my broadband connection, I'm not able to disconnect (relevant line is greyed out).

So what is going on here???

Maybe a permission problem? I don't have a clue where to look. syslog didn't provide any hints.

Regards,
Oliver

Answer (score 1):

I posted an easier solution here with links to just download the ubuntu2.3 version of network-manager-gnome which is all you need.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1424119

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with lubuntu-desktop and this is how I solved the problem. The problem was my interfaces file: `/etc/network/interfaces`.

After trying Ubuntu with the Unity interface I decided I didn't like it because it was a memory hog. So I decided to start with the Ubuntu server version and build up from there. In order to get the internet working on the server version I had to manually edit the interfaces file with my wifi settings. When I installed the lubuntu-desktop I had problems described here in this thread. But the solution was to remove the wifi settings in the interfaces file and reboot. Boom, it is working like a champ. I've got a ways to go before I get my system the way I want it but baby steps.

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` should look like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```